# Write output of CircuitPython program to file

Tags: python, embedded, microcontroller, micropython, adafruit-circuitpython

Similarly to how CircuitPython automatically writes the output of `boot.py` to `boot_out.txt`, how can I get the output of `code.py` (including error messages) to go into something like `code_out.txt`?

([CDC is disabled](https://learn.adafruit.com/customizing-usb-devices-in-circuitpython/circuitpy-midi-serial) because I had [too many USB endpoints](https://learn.adafruit.com/customizing-usb-devices-in-circuitpython/how-many-usb-devices-can-i-have), so I can't see the error messages via serial connection.)

Comment: Use os.dupterm to echo the console output to a file.  See http://www.bukys.eu/blog/210105_log_micropython_console_text_to_file?do=edit for an example.

Comment: Sounds like you don't want to dump code.py to a file,  but that you want to see errors and other useful runtime information. If that's the case, use the CP logging library.  https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_Logging

Comment: @RussHughes `os` in CircuitPython doesn't have `dupterm()`. And `io` doesn't have `IOBase`. Do you have any ideas for workarounds?

Comment: @Patrick The example from your link doesn't seem to create a file nor to mention how to create a file. Thoughts?

Comment: @root checkout the examples in the examples folder in the library repo.